# Split Panel using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to code a split panel, Left and right. Each will have a button which you can click on and it will toggle that panel, while expanding the other.

I am clueless as to where to start off? Is there an example that already does this?

Can someone help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this example. Check it out http://jsbin.com/ekabe5.
You can just change the style of the div to toggle or expand it.